# Mixed gradients of 1/r

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I am quite confused on how to evaluate successive mixed gradients of functions of the form $f(r)/r$, appearing often as potential in physics. In particular, I was reading [this paper](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/104/13/5094/480030/A-new-generalization-of-the-Casimir-Polder?redirectedFrom=fulltext), where Eq. (3.3) is

$$ H_{ijk}(uR) = (-\nabla^2\delta_{ij} + \nabla_i \nabla_j)\nabla_k \frac{e^{-uR}}{R} $$

While the paper gives the result of this expression, I tried to evaluate it myself, but I can't see how the components work for the successive gradients.

In particular, I understand that $\nabla \frac{1}{R}=-\frac{\hat{R}}{R^2}$, so I'm pretty sure that $\nabla_k \frac{1}{R}=-\frac{\hat{R}_k}{R^2}$. Then, in the next step, I should take $\nabla_j$ of this result, and since I assume $\nabla_j \hat{R}_k=0$, I would get

$\nabla_j \nabla_k \frac{1}{R}=\delta_{jk} \frac{2 \hat{R}_k}{R^3}$

I am pretty sure that already  at this step my derivation is incorrect, and I assume it is because the mixed derivative does not give $\delta_{jk}$, but I can't  see why.

Could anyone walk me through how to obtain the components of this successive gradient expression?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $$f(r)=\frac{e^{-ur}}{r}$$ with $r = \| \mathbf{x} \|$.
Using the concept of differentials, it holds
$$
df=
-
\left[
u+\frac{1}{r} 
\right]f dr=
-
\left[
u+\frac{1}{r} 
\right]\frac{f}{r} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}
$$
since $dr = 
\frac{1}{r} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}$.

From here, denote $$
\phi
=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}
= - \left[ u+\frac{1}{r} \right] \frac{f}{r} x_k
$$

The gradient writes
$$
\mathbf{g}
=
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\left[3+3ur+u^2 r^2\right]
\frac{f x_k}{r^4}
\mathbf{x}
- \left[ u+\frac{1}{r} \right]
\frac{f}{r}
\mathbf{e}_k 
$$
with $\mathbf{e}_k$ the canonical vector basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The Hessian follows similarly and yields the requested formula.

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding why $\pmb{g}$ is the gradient. The function $\phi$ seems to contain the derivative of $f$ with respect to a coordinate $x_k$, so why is the gradient just a vector of $\phi$s, why does it need to be differentiated once more?

Comment: $\phi$ is the term $\nabla_k e^{-ur}/r$. You need to compute the Hessian of this scalar-valued function of $\mathbf{x}$. So first you compute the gradient (the derivative of $\phi$ wrt $\mathbf{x}$) and then compute the derivative of it to find the Hessian.